# Calculate balance with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, cumulative-sum

I have a table which contains the following data:

```
ID      In       Out 
1      100.00    0.00   
2       10.00    0.00   
3        0.00   70.00    
4        5.00    0.00    
5        0.00   60.00   
6       20.00    0.00
```

Now I need a query which gives me the following result:

```
ID      In       Out    Balance
1      100.00    0.00   100.00
2       10.00    0.00   110.00
3        0.00   70.00    40.00
4        5.00    0.00    45.00
5        0.00   60.00   -15.00
6       20.00    0.00     5.00
```

Is it possible to do this with one query, without using a trigger or stored procedures?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer, yes

Longer answer, you can use a variable to tally it up as it iterates down the rows, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    `table`.`ID`,
    `table`.`In`,
    `table`.`Out`,
    @Balance := @Balance + `table`.`In` - `table`.`Out` AS `Balance`
FROM `table`, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit
ORDER BY `table`.`ID` ASC
```

The `, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit` ensures that @Balance is initialised to 0 before you start.  For each row it then sets @Balance to be `@Balance + In - Out`, and then outputs the calculated value.

Also it's worth making certain the ORDER is consistent as otherwise the Balance will vary depending on what order the rows are returned.  If you wanted to then order it back to front, for example, you could use this as a subquery as then the outer query deals with the calculated values thus ensuring the Balance remains correct i.e.

```
SELECT
    `balanceCalculation`.`ID`,
    `balanceCalculation`.`In`,
    `balanceCalculation`.`Out`,
    `balanceCalculation`.`Balance`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `table`.`ID`,
        `table`.`In`,
        `table`.`Out`,
        @Balance := @Balance + `table`.`In` - `table`.`Out` AS `Balance`
    FROM `table`, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit
    ORDER BY `table`.`ID` ASC
) AS `balanceCalculation`
ORDER BY `balanceCalculation`.`ID` DESC
```

Comment: how with pagination, i think this query will not working well, the balance will not going well

Comment: @PutraLZendrato I'm afraid I don't understand the question

Comment: Hello Simon, I mean, how if the data row is big, Example, we have 100 data, but will not going load in one page. So, we separate into 2 page (pagination working). I think the running balance will not working.

Comment: You can limit the outer query as the subquery calculates derived values from the full dataset.  You can imagine `balanceCalculation` there as being just another table.  The limit does not change the totals, only the subset of data that you select from it.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to work with pagination?

Comment: @tinyCoder as long as you are ordering by ID, then you could do a subquery to `SELECT DISTINCT table.ID FROM table ORDER BY table.ID ASC LIMIT 0,10` for example, and then use that as an INNER JOIN within the `balanceCalculation` subquery.

Alternatively for the less efficient method you can just LIMIT the outer query.  But it would be more efficient to limit the IDs which are being summed up in the internal query.  But I already mentioned that in the comment from 2017.

Comment: Issue solved, check this if you where interested, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836805/double-entry-accounting-pagination-issue/

Comment: It will, but if you want to order based on totals over the whole table then you have no choice but to select the entire table.  You could add a WHERE clause to the subquery though if you are only interested in a specific set of rows, and then it will only sum up over that subset of data.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple answer would be:

```
SELECT `ID`, 
       `In`, 
       `Out`, 
       @running_bal := @running_bal + (`In` - `Out`)  as `Balance`
FROM   tableName, (SELECT @running_bal := 0) tempName
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` will suffice:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.In, t.Out, (SUM(t2.In) - SUM(t2.Out)) Balance
FROM mytable t
    LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON b2.ID <= b.ID
GROUP BY b.ID
```

Or subquery (which as it turns out is about twice as fast)

```
SELECT t.ID, t.In, t.Out,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.In) - SUM(t2.Out) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.ID <= t.ID) Balance
FROM mytable t;
```