# how to cause a trigger to calculate balances in an accounting software using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, triggers

Following to my earlier question that was answered, I would like to know how to do the similar balances calculations using postgres triggers.

[how to calculate balances in an accounting software using postgres window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110703/how-to-calculate-balances-in-an-accounting-software-using-postgres-window-functi/25110757?noredirect=1#comment39078623_25110757)

```
ID   Date         In       Out    Balance
1    1/1       100.00    0.00   100.00
2    2/1        10.00    0.00   110.00
3    3/1         0.00   70.00    40.00
4    5/1         5.00    0.00    45.00
5    6/1         0.00   60.00   -15.00
```

Now I need a "trigger" which gives me the following result:

```
ID   Date         In       Out    Balance
1    1/1        100.00    0.00   100.00
2    2/1         10.00    0.00   110.00
3    3/1          0.00   70.00    40.00
6    4/1         20.00    0.00    60.00  <--- inserted new row
4    5/1          5.00    0.00    65.00
5    6/1          0.00   60.00     5.00
```

How do I create a trigger in postgres to update balances of "successive" rows (dont update the older rows) ?

Comment: read [this](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/Meetup/Presentations/postgresql_stored_procedures.pdf)

Comment: @dude ... why? What's relevant there? Details please. Yes, this is a bit of a "do it for me" question but I'm not sure that link is helpful.

Comment: @CraigRinger  [this](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/Meetup/Presentations/postgresql_stored_procedures.pdf) pdf file nicely exaplined about `Triggers` with understandable example as you said the question is `"do it for me"` that will helps him to under stand triggers so that he can easly catch when an answer for his question is avaialble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually harder than it looks.

More than one person might concurrently be inserting a row, and their commit orders might not be the same as the order in which the rows are created. That means that a trigger calculating the balance won't see rows it should and the balance will be wrong.

To make this work reliably, you must `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` before doing an `INSERT`, or you must use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation in 9.2 or newer. Both introduce the need to re-try failed transactions:

- `SERIALIZABLE` will abort a problematic transaction and force you to re-try it; and
- Taking a lock in a trigger involves a *lock upgrade*, which can deadlock, causing the transaction to be aborted.

so your app must be prepared to re-try failed transactions.

To avoid this you can use `READ COMMITTED` isolation and have the app explicitly `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` the table of interest *before* it tries to do anything else with it, even `SELECT` from it, if it thinks it *might* later need to `INSERT` a row into it. However, concurrency will then suck somewhat.

So, given that, you'd write something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION balance_insert_trigger() 
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN 
    -- This can deadlock unless you already took the lock earlier
    -- in the transaction; we put it here only for safety to make
    -- sure to block concurrent inserts.
    LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

    IF tg_op = 'INSERT' THEN
        NEW.balance = (SELECT sum(in) - sum(out) FROM mytable);
        RETURN NEW
    ELSE
        -- It's not safe to DELETE FROM or UPDATE this table because of the
        -- running balance.
        RAISE EXCEPTION '% operation not permitted on this table', tg_op;
    END IF;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER balance_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE balance_insert_trigger();
```

then always:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO mytable ...;
COMMIT;
```

If you want to support `UPDATE` and `DELETE` too, then things get exciting.

Comment: wow, that looks very elaborate. Just mark in Answared first and try it later. Thanks a lot guys.