# rails controller filter on method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I make the clients/index show only clients with **negative balance**?

I have **Client.rb**:

```
has_many :incomes
has_many :expences

  def all_incomes
      incomes.map(&:amount).sum
  end
  def all_expences
      expences.map(&:amount).sum
  end
  def balance
    all_incomes - all_expences
  end
end
```

**ClientsController.rb:**

```
  def index
    @client = Client.where(:balance < 0)
  end
```

Taking into consideration, that "balance" is not saved as a column of the table in the database...

Comment: Sure, it would have worked if `balance` was saved in the database, but it is not. It is a field, calculated in the model...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to filter in Ruby:

```
class Client 
  def all_incomes
    incomes.map(&:amount).sum
  end
  def all_expences
    expences.map(&:amount).sum
  end
  def balance
    all_incomes - all_expences
  end

  def self.postive_balance
    self.all.select {|c| c.balance < 0 }
  end
end
```

However its going to be very inefficient given a large enough amount of clients. You should instead select aggregates of `incomes.amount` and `expenses.amount` and do the calculation on the database level.

- [how to calculate balances in an accounting software using postgres window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110703/how-to-calculate-balances-in-an-accounting-software-using-postgres-window-functi)

Answer (score 1):

```
  def index
    @client = Client.joins(:incomes,:expenses).having("SUM(incomes.amount) - SUM(expenses.amount) < 0")
  end
```

Join with both models and apply condition while querying as above. This will be much faster.