# How to calculate balance in accounting using postgres with join table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sum, window-functions

Ive got an issue same with this [calculate balance in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110703/how-to-calculate-balances-in-an-accounting-software-using-postgres-window-functi) but with join table.

I have table A with

```
ID      amount     deduct_id     created_time
1      100.00          1         2020-01-01 15:30:20
2       10.00          1         2020-01-01 15:32:20 
3       30.00          1         2020-01-01 15:43:20
4        5.00          1         2020-02-02 08:30:20
5       10.00          2         2020-02-02 23:30:20
6       20.00          2         2020-02-03 10:30:20
```

and table B with

```
deduct_id      amount      created_time
1              100.00      2020-02-02 10:00:20
2               15.00      2020-02-03 10:00:20
```

Now I need a query which gives me the following result:

```
ID     amount    deduct    Balance    created_time
1      100.00     0.00      100.00    2020-01-01 15:30:20
2       10.00     0.00      110.00    2020-01-01 15:32:20
3       30.00     0.00      140.00    2020-01-01 15:43:20
4        5.00     0.00      145.00    2020-02-02 08:30:20
null     0.00   100.00       45.00    2020-02-02 10:00:20
5       10.00     0.00       55.00    2020-02-02 23:30:20
null     0.00    15.00       40.00    2020-02-03 10:00:20
6       20.00     0.00       60.00    2020-02-03 10:30:20
```

i am using **postgres 9.6**

**deduct_id** is to indicate if a data is part of the deduction on that date.

**created_time** is to indicate timeline.

[Updated]
and how to achieve filter by month?

```
ID     amount    deduct    Balance    created_time
1      100.00     0.00      100.00    2020-01-01 15:30:20
2       10.00     0.00      110.00    2020-01-01 15:32:20
3       30.00     0.00      140.00    2020-01-01 15:43:20


ID     amount    deduct    Balance    created_time
4        5.00     0.00      145.00    2020-02-02 08:30:20
null     0.00   100.00       45.00    2020-02-02 10:00:20
5       10.00     0.00       55.00    2020-02-02 23:30:20
null     0.00    15.00       40.00    2020-02-03 10:00:20
6       20.00     0.00       60.00    2020-02-03 10:30:20
```

I know this is bad design of table, but is it possible to achieve that kind of result?
how would this be done?

thanks in advance, any help really appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify the roles of `deduct_id` and `created_time`, show what you tried, and disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: updated @ErwinBrandstetter
I want to use created_time to filter with WHERE condtion.
so I can get balance on spesific range of month, with starting balance is last balance on the previous month

Answer (score 2):

I think that's `union all`  and a window `sum()`:

```
select
    id,
    amount,
    deduct,
    sum(amount - deduct) over(order by created_time) balance,
    created_time
from (
    select id, amount, 0 as deduct, created_time from tablea
    union all 
    select null, 0 as amount, amount as deduct, created_time from tableb
) t
```

I am unclear on what column `deduct_id` is supposed to be used for. From the results of the query, it looks like you don't want to use it to define partitions, as opposed to what I would have thought - so I just removed if from the query.

Comment: hi, thanks your answer help me.
but if you dont mind, do you how to use WHERE created_time on the query?
so I can filter by date, with starting amount is last balance on the previous month? 
@GMB