# Calculate (General ledger like) using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I know it might be hard to achieve using eloquent, but  i don't seem to be giving up on the idea that it couldn't.

I have a table called `finances`, partial structure:

```
amount (float) 
type(varchar) - can take either "credit" or "debit"
date(date)
```

Now, what i want is: to calculate the "balance" after each transaction
Sample :

```
       Type    Amount   Balance   Date(dd/m/yyyy)  
--- -------- -------- --------- ----------------- 
1   credit   5.00     25.00     12-1-2014        
2   debit    10.00    20.00     11-1-2014        
3   debit    5.00     10.00     10-1-2014        
4   credit   15.00    15.00     09-1-2014
```

What's your suggestions using Eloquent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*SQL magic inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394475/1903366)*

It doesn't look very pretty but works. Alternatively you may consider creating a db view with the balance select to keep your code a bit cleaner.

```
Finance::select('id', 'amount', 'type', 'date',
                DB::raw('@balance := @balance + IF(type = "credit", amount, -amount) AS balance'))
         ->from(DB::raw('finances, (SELECT @balance := 0) AS balanceStart'))
         ->get();
```

### Use pagination

Because `paginate()` will only query a part of the records (and therefore return an incorrect balance) you have to do the pagination yourself... sort of. You can still use the `Paginator` class.

```
$allFinances = // query from above
$perPage = 10;
$pagination = App::make('paginator');
$count = $allFinances->count();
$page = $pagination->getCurrentPage($count);
$finances = $this->slice(($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
$items = $pagination->make($items, $count, $perPage);

// pass $items to the view
```

Comment: This looks amazing ! Thanks, what if i wanted to use ->paginate( ) ?

Comment: @AAlyusuf that should work fine. Just replace `->get()` with `->paginate()`

Comment: Yah but then balancestart would be the first element in the current page, not the whole table ( means it will start counting from the wrong number ) @lukasgeiter

Comment: How to use join in this case?