# Bigquery: Calculate balance or rewrite SQL script in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Please help. I'm trying to find a solution how to calculate the current balance for each row by having 'in' and 'out' and previous balance in BigQuery:
'Current Balance'= 'Previous Balance'+ 'in' - 'out'

I have:

```
| id | in |out|
| ---| ---|---|
|1   | 10 |0  |
|2   | 30 |5  |
|3   | 0  |1  |
```

expected result:

```
| id| in|out| Balance |
|---|---|---|---------|
|1  | 10|  0|       10|
|2  | 30|  5|       35|
|3  | 0 |  1|       34|
```

The same issue was raised here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394418/calculate-balance-with-mysql][1], but provided solution is for MySQL.

If there is a way how to transfer this to BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
    `table`.`ID`,
    `table`.`In`,
    `table`.`Out`,
    @Balance := @Balance + `table`.`In` - `table`.`Out` AS `Balance`
FROM `table`, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit
ORDER BY `table`.`ID` ASC
```

Or Are there any other options for calculating the balance in BigQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(initial_balance), 
  initial_balance + sum(t.in - t.out) over win as balance
from your_table t,
unnest([struct(0 as initial_balance)])
window win as (order by id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question and initial balance = 0 - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
SELECT SUM(IN) OVER(ORDER BY ID) - SUM(OUT) OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way how to add an initial balance?

Comment: Is tge intial bal stored in a variable